# Rails Custom relations error has_many and has_one in the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, migration, relation

this is my relation:

```
create_table :decks do |t|
    t.references :user, index: true
    t.string :name

    t.timestamps
end

create_table :users do |t|
    t.references :choosen_deck, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :decks }
    t.integer :hp
    t.integer :armor

    t.timestamps
end
```

Relation:

=> user.rb

```
  has_many :decks, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :choosen_deck, class_name: 'Deck', dependent: :destroy
```

=> deck.rb

```
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :choosen_deck, class_name: 'User'
```

this is my migration, I want to have this kind of relations:

=> user.choosen_deck

=> user.decks

=> deck.user

But it doesn't work because I can't save the deck model.
Do you have an idea ?

UPDATE:

=> this is the trace

```
2.4.1 :002 > d = Deck.new(name: "Deck t")
(0.5ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
=> #<Deck id: nil, user_id: nil, name: "Deck t", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.1 :003 > u = User.new(hp: 20, armor: 20, choosen_deck: d)
=> #<User id: nil, choosen_deck_id: nil, hp: 20, armor: 20, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.1 :004 > d.user
=> #<User id: nil, choosen_deck_id: nil, hp: 20, armor: 20, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.1 :005 > d.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`hp`, `armor`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (20, 20, '2018-05-01 13:53:18', '2018-05-01 13:53:18')
Deck Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `decks` (`user_id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 'Deck t', '2018-05-01 13:53:18', '2018-05-01 13:53:18')
(5.7ms)  COMMIT
=> true 
2.4.1 :007 > d2 = Deck.create(name: "Deck 2", user: u)
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Deck Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `decks` (`user_id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 'Deck 2', '2018-05-01 13:53:57', '2018-05-01 13:53:57')
(4.0ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Deck id: 2, user_id: 1, name: "Deck 2", created_at: "2018-05-01      13:53:57", updated_at: "2018-05-01 13:53:57"> 
2.4.1 :008 > u
=> #<User id: 1, choosen_deck_id: nil, hp: 20, armor: 20, created_at: "2018-05-01 13:53:18", updated_at: "2018-05-01 13:53:18"> 
2.4.1 :009 > u.choosen_deck
=> #<Deck id: 1, user_id: 1, name: "Deck t", created_at: "2018-05-01 13:53:18", updated_at: "2018-05-01 13:53:18"> 
2.4.1 :010 > u.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true 
2.4.1 :011 > d.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true 
2.4.1 :012 > d2.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm not sure what you intended by:

```
belongs_to :choosen_deck, class_name: 'User'
```

In terms of creating your records, I think you should be able to do something like:

```
user = User.create!(hp: 20, armor: 20)
user.create_choosen_deck!(name: "Deck t")
user.decks.create!(name: "Deck 2")
```

`create_choosen_deck` and `decks.create` are methods provided by the association declaration (see the [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more information). If you use these methods, then the `user_id` value will be set automatically.

(BTW, it's `chosen`, not `choosen`.)

Comment: Hello, your answer work but the "chosen_deck_id" still nil do you have an idea ? If I do a user.choosen_deck = deck it's work but if I only look in database choose_deck_id still nil

Comment: Well, you don't show any code where you're trying to set `chosen_deck`. If you add that to your question, I can take a look. BTW, you would have to do a `user.save` in order for the `chosen_deck_id` to be saved to the database. If you're still having problems, you can do `user.valid?` and then examine `user` for errors.

Comment: u.chosen_deck works but u don't show the deck id in chosen_deck_id

Comment: A couple of things. When you assign `u = User.new(hp: 20, armor: 20, choosen_deck: d)`, `d` doesn't have an `id` yet because it hasn't been saved. So, `chosen_deck_id` can't be set. Also, this is rails 5? If so, `belongs_to` defaults to required `true`. You may need to change that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yeah but how it's work for rails if my user requires my deck and my deck requires my user ?

Comment: Updated answer.